# Add a value of year or any column for a folder in windows explorer win7

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 Professional (32-bit). I know i can add ratings, authors, title attributes to a file but what about folders? Actually I have large data of all my projects in their respective folders. Currently I have a nice detail view of my "projects" folder showing my several project directories. Now I have added a "Year" column to this view but I cannot find a way to add a "year attribute" to my individual project folder so that I can also sort my projects by year. How can I do that?

I cannot sort by "date created" or "date modified" since I copy/create the folders among different PCs

Comment: Different file types support different types of metadata, but that's not the case with file system structures such as folders. The easiest solution IMO would be to add the year to the beginning of the project folder names.

Comment: I think windows 7 doesn't have it. @Karan I've already implemented your solution before asking here. Thanks :)